# How do I ".Wait( )" on a ConfiguredTaskAwaitable?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Given the following extension to prevent `Tasks` from blocking the UI Thread ( probably not the exact correct terminology but whatever ) :

```
    public static ConfiguredTaskAwaitable DontBlock( this Task T ) {
        return T.ConfigureAwait( false );
    }

    public static ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<T> DontBlock<T>( this Task<T> T2 ) {
        return T2.ConfigureAwait( false );
    }
```

In some cases ( such as if I need to call an awaitable within an object constructor, or if I need to call `.Wait( )` from a WinForms `Program.Main( )` method), I need to do the following :

```
public class Foo{
    public Foo( ){
        //I know full well that the result from DontBlock does not have a 'wait' method, so of course this will fail miserably.
        AwaitableBar.DontBlock( ).Wait( );
    }
}
```

How can I 'await' it outside an `async` function/method if I can't call `.Wait( )` on it? I see that it has a `.GetAwaiter( )` method which returns a `ConfiguredTaskAwaiter` object, but I have no idea what to do with it, and Google has failed me again... Am I supposed to call `GetResult( )` on the returned object right away? Will doing that wait for everything to finish, or just skip right over it, or explode?

Comment: if you wait for something outside an async function it will block the UI no matter how the task was configured.

Comment: The key methods in `await` are `IsCompleted`, `GetResult()` if that is `true`, and `OnCompleted(Action)` if that is `false`. However, doing this is much harder than just using `await`. If you absolutely need to `Wait()`, then... well, frankly you shouldn't be using an `async`-style method in the first place, but you could create any blocking primitive and use `OnCompleted` to release it when the task completes.

Comment: @MarcGravell In most cases I don't need to call .Wait( ); in most cases I do use the full `await/async` all the way to the bottom (and thanks to one of your posts on another question which I read which mentioned the ConcigureAwaitable, that is now a staple in my design philosophy); however, in some cases (READ : WinForms Program.Main( ), Object Constructors), I do find it necessary to use an awaitable outside of an asynchronous context...

Comment: @Will frankly, I would suggest refactoring so that you don't need to do it in the constructor, etc

Comment: This is totally off topic but I advise against using this whitespace style. it deviates from the community standard for no discernible reason. Conformance is the most important goal for code style.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree with the @usr that returning a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` is not ideal. Generally, your asynchronous methods should return tasks. This is a matter of separation of concerns.

Once you have a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`, though, simply call `awaitableObj.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` (or the appropriate substitution). `GetResult()` will block.

Comment: Regardless of how hair brained and inane my question is, this is the answer for which I was looking; Thank you.

Comment: I am working with a WPF + ASP.NET web api application and since project is too big to change in a one go, I am working with async along with ConfigureAwait(false) to wait on it so that rest of call hierarchy is unchanged. But when I call GetResult on ConfiguredTaskAwaitable debugger just disappears and nothing is returned to client application. Any help?

Comment: @AshutoshSingh Sounds like you are blocking. Are you sure the task completes? GetResult is a blocking call that waits for completion of the task.

Answer (score 11):

Probably, you should not return a `ConfiguredTaskAwaitable` from anything. This is a helper type that is only needed in the `await t.ConfigureAwait( false)` pattern. `await t.DontBlock()` is also fine but don't pass this type around. I see no purpose in doing so.

You seem to believe that `ConfigureAwait(false)` unblocks the UI thread. Not so. Waiting always blocks a thread. Blocking means that this thread cannot continue execution. `Wait` causes that condition if the underlying task is not completed.

So probably, what you wanted to accomplish doing that is not accomplished. Use `await` on the UI thread. Use `Wait()` on non-UI-threads if you want to block.

`AwaitableBar.DontBlock( ).Wait()` tell me you have some wrong belief. Here, `DontBlock` does not unblock anything. It does nothing even if this code worked.

If it was that easy to unblock a thread, why would we need `await` at all?!

Comment: I found this question looking to do exactly what Will is talking about, and `DontBlock` is probably a misnomer and the more accurate statement would be `DontDeadlock`. If on the UI thread you synchronously `Wait()` on an async method that does not use `ConfigureAwait(false)`, then you will end up deadlocking the UI thread. Sometimes you end up needing to synchronously wait like in constructors or Dispose methods.