# SendGrid API v3 post breaks example

Tags: .net, sendgrid

I've upgraded to SendGrid API v3 for my ASP.Net project and found a problem with the old code for sending emails within the IIdentityMessageService.SendAsync function.

My code is as follows:

```
Public Class EmailService
    Implements IIdentityMessageService

    Public Function SendAsync(message As IdentityMessage) As Task Implements IIdentityMessageService.SendAsync
        Dim sg = New SendGridAPIClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SendGridApiKey"))

        Dim from = New Email("support@investorsedge.net", "InvestorsEdge")
        Dim [to] = New Email(message.Destination)
        Dim Content = New Content("text/html", message.Body)
        Dim Mail = New Mail(from, message.Subject, [to], Content)

        Dim response = sg.client.mail.send.post(requestBody:=Mail.Get()).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        If Not response.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted Then
            AtlasDb.Log.ErrorFormat("EmailService.SendAsync", "Abnormal response code ({0}", response.StatusCode)
        End If

        Return Task.FromResult(response.StatusCode)
    End Function
End Class
```

This code worked fine in API v2, but I now get a System.MissingMemberException when accessing the response object.

In the new examples the post is awaited, but I can;t change the SendAsync signature to Async as it's not my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in another SO post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248047/how-do-i-wait-on-a-configuredtaskawaitable) - the object returned by post is now a ConfiguredAwaitable object - the result can be accessed by .GetAwaiter().GetResult() as below:

```
Public Class EmailService
    Implements IIdentityMessageService

    Public Function SendAsync(message As IdentityMessage) As Task Implements IIdentityMessageService.SendAsync
        Dim sg = New SendGridAPIClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SendGridApiKey"))

        Dim from = New Email("support@investorsedge.net", "InvestorsEdge")
        Dim [to] = New Email(message.Destination)
        Dim Content = New Content("text/html", message.Body)
        Dim Mail = New Mail(from, message.Subject, [to], Content)

        Dim response = sg.client.mail.send.post(requestBody:=Mail.Get()).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
        If Not response.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted Then
            AtlasDb.Log.ErrorFormat("EmailService.SendAsync", "Abnormal response code ({0}", response.StatusCode)
        End If

        Return Task.FromResult(response.StatusCode)
    End Function
End Class
```

I'm not sure in normal code how this would perform with regards to blocking the UI, but figure that as this runs in a seperate thread within ASP.Net the effects wouldn't be too bad.